# bash - How to create a disk/partition menu?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I tried some code from [unix.com](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/116164-bash-script-get-all-mounted-devices.html), modifying it to act as a device selector.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
for device in `fdisk -l | sed -n '/^[/]/p' | awk '{print $1}'`
do
  count=$((count+1))
  dev[$count]=$device
  echo "$count: $device"
done
echo "Select volume (numbers 1-$count):"
read selected_number
selected_device=$dev[$selected_number] 
echo "The device you selected is: $selected_device"
```

for some reason the line `selected_device=$dev[$selected_number]` is not working as expected.
I imagine I did some beginner's syntax error.

the output it gives is

```
1: /dev/nvme0n1p1
2: /dev/nvme0n1p2
3: /dev/nvme0n1p3
4: /dev/nvme0n1p4
5: /dev/nvme0n1p5
6: /dev/nvme0n1p6
7: /dev/nvme0n1p7
8: /dev/mmcblk0p1
Select volume (numbers 1-8):
5
The device you selected is: [5]
```

while I would expect something like `The device you selected is: /dev/nvme0n1p5`

(I'm running the script as sudo, btw)

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try with: `selected_device=${dev[$selected_number]}`

Comment: Instead of implementing `select` logic yourself, use bash's select : `help select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=0

for device in `fdisk -l | sed -n '/^[/]/p' | awk '{print $1}'`; do
  count=$((count+1))
  dev[$count]=$device
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$count" "$device"
done

read -rp "Select volume (numbers 1-$count): " selected_number

printf 'The device you selected is: %s\n' "${dev[$selected_number]}"
```

---

Although I suggest to use a `while` + `read` loop with [Process Substitution.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```
while IFS= read -r device; do
  count=$((count+1))
  dev[$count]=$device
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$count" "$device"
done < <(fdisk -l | sed -n '/^[/]/p' | awk '{print $1}')
```

---

Also the `sed` and  `awk` part can be just one `awk`

```
fdisk -l | awk '/^[/]/{print $1}'
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, but I would like to save the result to a variable. the final "echo" was only to test the script

Comment: @DavidePacchiarotti, you mean like `variable=${dev[$selected_number]}` ?

Comment: ok, I missed the {} parenthesis, thanks! now it works!